# Failed to apply XSLT to the content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, 2013, xslt, xml-viewer-web-part

I am using "XML Viewer" webpart to display some data from another website. I have applied XSL on it and it works fine on my VM. But when I moved the site to development server, it showed error message "Failed to apply XSLT to the content".

I see there is another thread on this exact topic but it doesn't say anything except that it has to something to do with services packs and updates on VM.

How can I solve this problem on development machine?

I am using applying XSL using XSLT editor in that web part.

Comment: Anyone?????????